# How to create a makefile but don't compile?

Tags: makefile

I am now want to create a makefile but don't compile anything

I have a `liba.so`

I want to check if the dependence libs was installed and copy it to a path

I try it in makefile by

```
INSTALL_PATH = /usr/local/myapp/


liba:libc.dylib libd,dylib libe.dylib
[tab]echo 'Setting complete!'
install: liba liba.doc 
[tab]cp liba liba.doc $(INSTALL_PATH)
```

but it will report

```
make: *** No rule to make target `libc.dylib', needed by `ll'.  Stop.
```

hoe to fix it?

or any better option to get my goal?

Comment: Have you wrote a makefile before? These files "libc.dylib libd,dylib libe.dylib" seem to not exist.

Comment: This is my first time to do it ,I know where  `libc.dylib libd,dylib libe.dylib`is,but I don't know how to make it knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to list full paths in the prerequisite list (right side of the <kbd>:</kbd>) of your liba target.

Your install target rule is also not quite accurate since you said you are trying to install your `liba.so` file (not `liba` as you have listed).

I'm not sure that using make for this is exactly the best tool for the job (though it will work fine when things are installed in the appropriate places).